# Manejar evento OnClick en ASP

Tags: asp.net, asp, gridview

tengo este código que me saca una tabla con notas y no me funciona el evento "EliminarNota_Click".

```
  Protected Sub CargarNotasGuardadas()
   

    Dim c As String = nodoSel.Value
    Dim id_Toma As String = c.Substring(0, c.IndexOf("_"))


    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Using selectCommand As New SqlCommand(query, connection)
            selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_toma", id_Toma)

            connection.Open()

            Dim notasGuardadas As New List(Of String)()
            Dim fechasGuardadas As New List(Of String)()

            Using reader As SqlDataReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader()
                While reader.Read()
                    notasGuardadas.Add(reader.GetString(0))
                    fechasGuardadas.Add(reader.GetDateTime(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
                End While
            End Using

            ' Generar el HTML para las notas guardadas en una tabla con estilos CSS
            Dim notasHTML As New StringBuilder()
            notasHTML.Append("<table class=""notas-table"">")
            notasHTML.Append("<tr><th>Nota</th><th>Fecha</th></tr>")
            For i As Integer = 0 To notasGuardadas.Count - 1
                notasHTML.Append("<tr>")
                notasHTML.Append("<td>" + notasGuardadas(i) + "</td>")
                notasHTML.Append("<td>" + fechasGuardadas(i) + "</td>")
                notasHTML.Append("<td><button class=""eliminarNotas-btn"" id=""EliminarNota"" data-toggle=""modal"" runat=""server"" data-idToma=""" + id_Toma + """ OnClick=""EliminarNota_Click"">Eliminar</button></td>")
                notasHTML.Append("<td><button class=""editarNotas-btn"" id=""editarNota"" data-toggle=""modal""  runat=""server"" OnClientClick=""Return False;"">Editar</button></td>")
                notasHTML.Append("</tr>")
            Next
            notasHTML.Append("</table>")

            notasGuardadasLiteral.Text = notasHTML.ToString()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Cuando escribo Portected Sub EliminarNota_Click... no me lo detecta, en la depuración tampoco me salta el evento. He probado con mensajes por consola por si acaso se me pasaba algo pero tampoco.

EDICION:
He convertido la tabla en un gridview pero este no se muestra aunque he depurado el codigo y este recoge todo bien, cuando llega a GridViewNotas.DataSoruce y a GridViewNotas.DataBind la tabla se recoge correctamente pero a la hora de mostrarla me aparece un div vacío.

Este es el GridView:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridViewNotas" runat="server" visible="true" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Nota" DataField="notas" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Fecha" DataField="fecha_nota" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Acciones">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="EliminarNota" runat="server" CssClass="eliminarNotas-btn" Text="Eliminar" CommandName="Eliminar" OnCommand="GridViewNotas_Command" />
                        <asp:Button ID="EditarNota" runat="server" CssClass="editarNotas-btn" Text="Editar" CommandName="Editar" OnCommand="GridViewNotas_Command" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Y esta es la parte servidor que como he comentado, he depurado y recoge todos los datos bien.

```
 Protected Sub CargarNotasGuardadas()
        Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=DESKTOP-NGVFUAS\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=notas-canalJucarTuria;Integrated Security=True"
        Dim query As String = "SELECT notas, fecha_nota FROM [notas-canalJucarTuria] WHERE id_toma = @id_toma"

        Dim c As String = nodoSel.Value
        Dim id_Toma As String = c.Substring(0, c.IndexOf("_"))

        Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            Using selectCommand As New SqlCommand(query, connection)
                selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_toma", id_Toma)

                connection.Open()

                Dim notasTable As New DataTable()
                notasTable.Load(selectCommand.ExecuteReader())

                If notasTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                    GridViewNotas.DataSource = notasTable
                    GridViewNotas.DataBind()
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
    Protected Sub GridViewNotas_Command(sender As Object, e As CommandEventArgs)
        If e.CommandName = "Eliminar" Then
            Dim idNota As String = e.CommandArgument.ToString()
            ' Código para eliminar la nota según el ID
        ElseIf e.CommandName = "Editar" Then
            Dim idNota As String = e.CommandArgument.ToString()
            ' Código para editar la nota según el ID
        End If
    End Sub
```

Lo que contiene DataSource:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No puedes crearlo dinamicamente  porque el ASP no lo va a interpretar a menos que cargues la pagina nuevamente, pero perderas  la tabla. Quizá deberias tener la tabla desde el inicio con el atributo "no visible" y hacerla visible en tu metodo "CargaNotasGuardadas", al menos es la forma más simple.

Comment: y como podría tenerla desde el inicio si los datos los manejo desde servidor

Comment: He probado a hacerla fuera y añadirle los botones con javascript pero tampoco me deja

Comment: ¿cómo es tu formulario ASP?

Comment: Para que un botón en HTML pueda invocar una función en el servidor, el botón debe estar en el `ViewState`, como tu estas creando el botón en un string dentro de un `literal` esto no será nunca posible. Lo más fácil es usar un  DataGrid o GridView (ya no recuerdo el nombre) o un `repeater` para generar una tabla dinámicamente, pudiendo agregar los botones en ella

Comment: Hola, he modificado la pregunta añadiendo los cambios que he hecho. He añadido un GridView pero no se muestra. Gracias.